# Independence of the statement that a union of $<\mathfrak{c}$ many measure zero sets has measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, set-theory

I read that that the statement that a union of fewer than continuum many measure zero sets has measure zero is independent of $\sf{ZFC}$. Is there a standard reference to this result?

Comment: I mean, we know for sure that the union of countably many is measure zero so this sounds like a fancy version of the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: @TSF I do believe that's the easy part. I'm sure, like most independence results, we'll have to build a nice model. But I'm more concerned about just reading it right now.

Comment: It is covered in Kunen's (newer) book as well. See corollary V.4.16

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the book by [Bartoszyński and Judah](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/156881044X) is one of the standard references for this kind of result (especially, cardinal characteristics of the continuum that are related to null and meager ideals.) Let me sketch how you can construct a proof.

On the one hand, Martin's axiom $\mathsf{MA}$ proves that the union of $<\mathfrak{c}$ null sets is always null. You can see the proof of the consistency of Martin's axiom in some textbooks about forcing (if it covers iterated forcing. Jech and Kunen certainly mention it.)

*(Note. I realized that Martin's axiom is overkill. Just assuming the continuum hypothesis suffices. However, Martin's axiom shows that the union of $<\mathfrak{c}$ null sets is still null regardless of what the value of $\mathfrak{c}$ is.)*

On the other hand, establishing the consistency of the *negation* of your statement is usually stated in the following combinatorial form: can we force the following cardinal

$$\mathsf{add}(\mathcal{N}):= \min\{\kappa : \text{the union of some $\kappa$ null sets is not null}\}$$

strictly less than $\mathfrak{c}$? Section 7.3.A of Bartoszyński and Judah discusses how to force $\mathsf{add}(\mathcal{N})<\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: Wonderful, wonderful. Thank you so much.